# How to toggle Error on values change in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, slds

This code shows permanent red border which i want to toggle based on selection of values. If no value is selected, then only it should show the red border and the message otherwise not. How can I do that?

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-has-error">
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">
<abbr class="slds-required" title="required">* </abbr>Select Label</label>
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
<div class="slds-select_container">
<select aria-describedby="error-01" class="slds-select" id="select-01" required="">
<option value="">Select…</option>
<option>Option One</option>
<option>Option Two</option>
<option>Option Three</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element__help" id="error-01">Select an option.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `lightning-select`?

Comment: No I did not try. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

By Adding Custom validation onchange={functionName} on the select tag (HTML file) and handle the error by javascript file where you can toggle the state by capturing the selected data either through custom SLDS or by throwing an error on screen.

Comment: Can you help me with this slds-has-error property? how to make it dynamic? <div class="slds-form-element slds-has-error">